# turn html into string but keep all html tags javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have an array of html. I am trying to run remainderHtml.toString() but result is

[object HTMLLabelElement],[object HTMLLabelElement],[object HTMLLabelElement]

How can I run a toString command (or any other command) and create an html string Exactly like my array? I do not want to remove the tags, or extract any data, just plain want to make this array of html one long connected string...

Here is my array of html from the console.log

```
(4) [label.p-1.font-weight-bold.bg-primary.ml-2.text-white.rounded-capsule.shadow-none.fs--3, label.p-1.font-weight-bold.bg-primary.ml-2.text-white.rounded-capsule.shadow-none.fs--3, label.p-1.font-weight-bold.bg-primary.ml-2.text-white.rounded-capsule.shadow-none.fs--3, label.p-1.font-weight-bold.bg-primary.ml-2.text-white.rounded-capsule.shadow-none.fs--3]
```

When I put the above into a variable called remainderHtml and try to run a toString() on it, I get [object HTMLLabelElement],[object HTMLLabelElement],[object HTMLLabelElement]

When I click on the arrow in the console to show the html array I get this below

```
0: label.p-1.font-weight-bold.bg-primary.ml-2.text-white.rounded-capsule.shadow-none.fs--3
1: label.p-1.font-weight-bold.bg-primary.ml-2.text-white.rounded-capsule.shadow-none.fs--3
2: label.p-1.font-weight-bold.bg-primary.ml-2.text-white.rounded-capsule.shadow-none.fs--3
3: label.p-1.font-weight-bold.bg-primary.ml-2.text-white.rounded-capsule.shadow-none.fs--3
length: 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to loop through your array and get the element's outerHTML

```
var allHTML = "";
remainderHtml.forEach(function (elem) {
  allHTML += elem.outerHTML;
});
```

Comment: that worked... Wow I was creating another function, looping turning into string, using regex etc... this was all I needed. thank you

Comment: @ErikaPeterson007 If this solved your problem, please click the checkmark next to the score on the left of the answer

Comment: your bio is impressive, But not going to college is deal breaker for me. sry